# Ricci curvature of fibrations

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature, kahler-manifolds

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a surjective holomorphic submersion between compact Kähler manifolds. Assume the fibres are positive-dimensional. Suppose the base $Y$ and fibres $F$ admit Kähler metrics of negative (respectively, zero, or positive) Ricci curvature. Does $X$ admit a Kähler metric whose Ricci curvature has the same sign?

Comment: Not generally. As a simple example, the second Hirzebruch surface, the completion of the cotangent bundle of $\mathbf{CP}^1$, has base and fibre $\mathbf{CP}^1$ but is not Fano, so has no Kähler metric of positive Ricci curvature.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you, this is a nice simple example. Is it true for zero or negative Ricci? It is easier to obstruct positive Ricci than it is to obstruct negative Ricci :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Also, I've never heard of the expression "completion of the tangent bundle". Can you explain?

Comment: Here, _completion_ refers to adding a trivial bundle and projectivizing, a.k.a., adding a section at infinity. <> I didn't think very hard about the non-positive case, hence the comment rather than an answer. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for this :)